# Could not import json file to d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, import, word-cloud

Could not import json file to d3.js

Hello everyone. I’m newbie in JS. I had tried to find solution of my problem but I didn’t find  anything.
I have a problem with importing JSON file to d3.js code. I tried to do this in many ways and I always have the similar error: “TypeError: myWords.map is not a function at reader.onload” or bad import with output like this: "object Object"

This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery@master/LIB/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var uploadButton = $('<input type="file">');
let x = uploadButton.change(function() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    var target = e.target;
    var data = JSON.parse(target.result);
    console.log(data);

var myWords = [];
myWords = data;

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 1024 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 1024 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
  .size([width, height])
  .words(myWords.map(function(d) { return {text: d}; }))
  .padding(10)
  .fontSize(30)
  .on("end", draw);
layout.start();
    
function draw(words) {
  svg
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + layout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + layout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
      .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
      .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}

return data
  }
  reader.readAsText(uploadButton[0].files[0]);
});
$('body').append(uploadButton);

</script>
```

Comment: `.map` is a function available for javascript arrays. Here, `myWord` is an object, not an array, as per `myWords = data;`.

Comment: @Mehdi Thank you for your answer. I tried to convert object to map const map1 = new Map(Object.entries(data)); But I still have errors at this place ".words(map1.map(function(d) { return {text: d}; }))" Error:"Un caught TypeError: map1.map is not a function at reader.onload"..... Can you help me, please...